# How to declare multiple QML properties without handling each one individually?

Tags: qt, properties, qml

I've got a toy QML app (Qt 5.7) that consists of the following QML page plus some C++ code that allows the QML to subscribe to some state on an audio device and reflect that state in the QML GUI.  The toy QML looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Item {
   id: deviceState

   property bool mute1: false
   property bool mute2: false
   property bool mute3: false
   property bool mute4: false

   Component.onCompleted: {
      // Call out to C++ land, to tell the server what 
      // control points we are interested in tracking the state of
      topLevelWindow.subscribeToControlPoints("Input 1-4 Mute", deviceState);
   }

   // Called by C++ land to tell us the current state of
   // a control point we previously subscribed to.
   function onControlPointValueUpdated(address, value) {
      if (address == "Input 1 Mute") {
         mute1 = value
      }
      else if (address == "Input 2 Mute") {
         mute2 = value
      }
      else if (address == "Input 3 Mute") {
         mute3 = value
      }
      else if (address == "Input 4 Mute") {
         mute4 = value
      }
   }

   // Absurdly minimalist example GUI
   Text {
      text: parent.mute4 ? "MUTED" : "unmuted"
   }
}
```

When I run this, my C++ code calls onControlPointValueUpdated() whenever one of the four mute-states on my audio device changes, and based on the 'address' argument in the call, one of the four muteN QML properties is changed.  And, whenever the mute4 property is changed, the text in the Text area is updated to reflect that.

This all works fine, as far as it goes, but at some point I'm going to need to scale it up; in particular I will need to track hundreds or thousands of values rather than just four, and having to manually declare an individual, hand-named QML property for each value would quickly become arduous and difficult to maintain; and the implementation of onControlPointValueUpdated() would become very inefficient if it has to manually if/elseif its way through every property.

So my question is, is there some way in QML for me to declare an array (or better yet, a dictionary/map) of properties, so that I can declare a large number of QML properties at once?  i.e. something like this:

```
property bool mutes[256]: {false}   // would declare mutes[0] through mutes[255], all default to false
```

... or if not, is there some other recommended approach to holding large amounts of observable state within a QML document?  I like the ability to have my GUI widgets bind to a QML property to get automatically updated as necessary, but it seems like perhaps QML properties weren't intended to be used *en masse*?

Comment: It depends on how you intend to present all of the variables. Currently you've got the "Absurdly minimalist example GUI" - what's the actual GUI going to look like? Will it be a list of `Text` items displaying those values?

Comment: Now, maybe I didn't understand, but you can't just create a Javascript object? Then you access it from text like `text: parent.obj.mute4 ? "MUTED" : "unmuted"` and you consider `undefined` as `false`? And the update `obj[property] = value`?

Comment: @Mitch probably something like a big grid of Buttons that turn red when a mute is active, or similar.  But I'm looking for a mechanism that would work well (i.e. efficiently, and with a minimum of QML-coding complexity) for any GUI I might come up with in the future.

Comment: @rpadovani possibly; I'm not very familiar with QML or Javascript yet so it's not clear to me whether that would work.  In particular, do members of a JavaScript object act as QML properties?  (i.e. would setting obj[property]=value cause the Text widget to update itself?)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a data-driven design here? (For instance a Repeater over some model)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some searching around, it appears the mechanism that best suits my current needs is the [`QQmlPropertyMap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlpropertymap.html) class.

In particular, I add a `QQmlPropertyMap` to my `QQmlContext`, and expose it to the QML world via `setContextProperty()`:

```
_sessionContext = new QQmlContext(_engine.rootContext());
_propertyMap = new QQmlPropertyMap(_sessionContext);
_sessionContext->setContextProperty("cps", _propertyMap);
```

... and then when I receive a value update in the C++ code, instead of calling a QML function, I just update the QQmlPropertyMap object with it:

```
_propertyMap->insert("input_4_mute", QVariant(true));  // arguments hard-coded here for clarity
```

... and all that remains to be done in the QML code is bind to the property however I want to:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 0; height: 0
    x:160; y:120
    color: cps.input_4_mute ? "red" : "blue"
}
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't even know about that class!

Answer (score 8):

As soon as you get a large amount of data that has to be displayed (especially if it all shares a common format), you should think about using a `QAbstractItemModel` derivative.

Another thing to point out is that it's not a good idea to call into the QML of the user interface from C++, because it tends to limit what you can do in QML, and ties the QML to the C++.

For example, if you were to display the data in a list:

[image: listview]

The items in the view are created on demand, and there are a limited amount that are allocated at any one time, which helps when you have a lot of data and potentially complex delegates.

Here's how a simple, custom `QAbstractListModel` with custom roles looks:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtQuick>

class UserModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    UserModel() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            mData.append(qMakePair(QString::fromLatin1("Input %1").arg(i), i % 5 == 0));
        }
    }

    enum Roles
    {
        NameRole = Qt::UserRole,
        MutedRole
    };

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        if (!index.isValid())
            return QVariant();

        switch (role) {
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
        case NameRole:
            return mData.at(index.row()).first;
        case MutedRole:
            return mData.at(index.row()).second;
        }

        return QVariant();
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &/*parent*/ = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        return mData.size();
    }

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &/*parent*/ = QModelIndex()) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        return 1;
    }

    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        QHash<int, QByteArray> names;
        names[NameRole] = "name";
        names[MutedRole] = "muted";
        return names;
    }

private:
    QVector<QPair<QString, int> > mData;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    UserModel userModel;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("userModel", &userModel);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        model: userModel
        spacing: 20

        delegate: ColumnLayout {
            width: ListView.view.width

            Text {
                text: name
                width: parent.width / 2
                font.pixelSize: 14
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }

            RowLayout {
                Rectangle {
                    width: 16
                    height: 16
                    radius: width / 2
                    color: muted ? "red" : "green"
                }

                Text {
                    text: muted ? qsTr("Muted") : qsTr("Unmuted")
                    width: parent.width / 2
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily swap the `ListView` out with a `GridView`, for example. Best of all, the C++ knows nothing about the QML.

You can read more about using C++ models with Qt Quick [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel-subclass).

---

Looking at the image you posted in the comments, that type of UI could be made in a couple of ways. You could use the approach above, but using a [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) in the delegate. The `Loader` can determine which type of [component](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) to show based on some data in the model. However, it looks like the amount of data displayed on your UI, while large in quantity, might indeed be better off without a view.

You could still use a model (e.g. with a `Repeater` like @peppe mentioned), but you could also get away with just listing off each "panel" (I dunno what they're called) in a similar way to how you're currently doing it. It looks like most of the data in one panel is the same, so each one could be its own class (untested code follows):

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtQuick>

class Panel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool muted READ muted WRITE setMuted NOTIFY mutedChanged)

    Panel() { /* stuff */ }

    // getters
    // setters

signals:
    // change signals

private:
    // members
};

class WeirdPanel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int level READ level WRITE setLevel NOTIFY levelChanged)

    WeirdPanel() { /* stuff */ }

    // getters
    // setters

signals:
    // change signals

private:
    // members
};

class Board : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Panel *panel1 READ panel1 CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(Panel *panel2 READ panel2 CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(Panel *panel3 READ panel3 CONSTANT)
    // etc.
    Q_PROPERTY(WeirdPanel *weirdPanel READ weirdPanel WRITE setWeirdPanel NOTIFY weirdPanelChanged)

public:

    Board() {
    }

    // getters
    // setters

signals:
    // change signals

private:
    Panel panel1;
    Panel panel2;
    Panel panel3;
    Panel panel4;
    WeirdPanel weirdPanel;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Board board;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("board", &board);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Panel {
            id: panel1
            panel: board.panel1
        }

        Panel {
            id: panel2
            panel: board.panel2
        }

        Panel {
            id: panel3
            panel: board.panel3
        }

        WeirdPanel {
            id: weirdPanel
            panel: board.weirdPanel
        }
    }
}
```

Then, `Panel.qml` might just be a column of buttons and whatnot:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Rectangle {
    property var panel

    color: "#444"

    implicitWidth: columnLayout.implicitWidth
    implicitHeight: columnLayout.implicitHeight

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Text {
            text: panel.name
            width: parent.width / 2
            font.pixelSize: 14
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }

        RowLayout {
            Rectangle {
                width: 16
                height: 16
                radius: width / 2
                color: panel.muted ? "red" : "green"
            }

            Text {
                text: panel.muted ? qsTr("Muted") : qsTr("Unmuted")
                width: parent.width / 2
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a problem with this approach is that displaying all the values together in a ListView (or GridView, or etc) is not going to be sufficient for my GUI; rather the GUI will need to provide an appropriate type of control for each type of data item it is associated with (i.e. toggle-buttons for mutes, faders for level controls, panpots for pan controls, etc).  Also it will need to be able to lay out those controls in various QML-file-defined ways, which I don't think a View would allow for.

Comment: Then that is something you should mention in your question. :) We're talking about a GUI toolkit here, after all.

Comment: But I find it hard to believe that anything but a view would be the right choice for "hundreds or thousands of values". I'll update my answer with some extra information that might help.

Comment: Here's a (randomly chosen) example of the sort of GUI that might be desired at some point:  http://wheatstone.com/images/NAB2016%20PR%20IMAGES/WHEATSTONE_LXE_CONSOLE.jpg

Comment: @JeremyFriesner You'll need to use appropriate delegates, then. You still want your data to be in a model of some sort.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you have specific questions about implementing the "panels", please ask another question for that.. it's getting quite long. :D

Comment: You're really into gifs these days. :D

Comment: They're so easy to make with Licecap, and they make boring old walls of text so much more interesting. :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It gives a nice touch to the answer.